# Best (and secure) way to call javascript function (with arguments) using a url from another page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, security, url

After reviewing dozens of Stack Overflow posts, I'm thoroughly confused. What I am trying to do is create a URL through an  tag on one page that would open another webpage and run a function that requires two arguments. I thought this would be simple but I keep seeing references to "cross site scripting vulnerabilities" and I am not familiar with this potential security problem and feel like I am now playing with fire. I do not want to utilize something — even if the code works — if it opens up security risks. Could someone point me in the right direction with the correct (and most secure) way to do this? I can do my research (and learning) from there. Much appreciated.

Comment: To avoid XSS, you should properly sanitize user input (e.g. Encode data on output
and Validate input on arrival). But it does not mean that you must disallow data transfer thru GET

Comment: Do you want to run a javascript function.
One way you can do this is to append some custom endpoint to your URL and when that URL is opened in a browser you can run a javascript or a php function as you want

Comment: What you need to do _depends on what sort of function_ you have there. Same principles apply as with any language accepting user input. Whatever you output, make sure it can't be "hijacked" with injected javascript, like `?text=<script>alert(1);</script>`. Otherwise, make sure any user  input used internally can't be modified to corrupt/compromise your code. Also see [XSS at OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can append some parameter at the end of your URL
https://your-url/?parameter=hello

When this URL is opened on another webpage you can run JavaScript or a PHP function based on that URL query.

For JavaScript

```js
getUrlParam(slug) {
        let url = new URL(window.location);
        let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
        let param = params.get(slug);
        if (param) {
            return param;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}

console.log(getUrlParam('parameter'));
```

After that, you can run this function to check if any parameter is passed in that URL or not.
If this function returns that's given slug parameter you can run your custom code inside that if condition block

Comment: Thank you for this information. I will see if I can figure this out and respond shortly. Much appreciated.

Comment: You can use this function in a If condition to check if that parameter is exits or not. If exits than you can run your custom code

Comment: But your initial url (URL https://your-url/?parameter=hello) does not include a call to a function so how does the called page know to run the function that contains the if statement? Sorry if this is basic ...

Comment: You can not call a function from a URL.
What you can do. is to write a function and call that function if that specific parameter is found in your URL

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. I will use your supplied code to practice that approach. Thank you!